# nicEdit panel disappear

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, nicedit

I have used nicEditor in my winforms application. Have taken a webrowser control onto my form and loaded nice editor on that. The issue is when I start typing and eneter a big text which occupies the the whole height , the fomatting panel of the nicedit disappears. Following is my code which I have written in an HTML file and then loaded the file onto my webbrowser control. Please also see the attached image. Is this because I am using the nicEditor inside winforms webbrowser.?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/nicEdit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
            myInstance = new nicEditor().panelInstance('editor');
            //nicEditors.allTextAreas() 
        });
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">
    <div id="sample">
        <textarea id="demo" cols="50" id="editor" name="editor" style="width: 300px; max-height: 150px;">
        </textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: yes, your winforms has a defined high, what should nicedit do if you put a text larger this, it growth down and the panel goes up, you can solve this if you separate the panel and fix it. Take a look in the nicedit wiki how to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I din get any help from its wiki. Can you share any link.?

Comment: This demo shows it http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=5 Or you can sticky the pannel look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571418/how-to-sticky-nicedit-panel